# Ordering a QuerySet by the first object in a prefetch_related query

Tags: django

If I have the following models, describing Books which can have several different Titles:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BookTitle(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="titles", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'm fetching a QuerySet of Books, pre-fetching their BookTitles, like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

books = Book.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "titles",
        queryset=BookTitle.objects.all()
    )
)
```

I'd like to be able to order the QuerySet by the first of the BookTitles. How would I do that?

(This is a very simplified example of my actual code to explain the basic question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you would like to order all books sorted by the first book title of each book.
You can do this by annotating the first book title to the query and then ordering by that:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch, OuterRef, Subquery


first_book = BookTitle.objects.filter(work=OuterRef("pk")).order_by("title")

Book.objects.annotate(
    first_book_name=Subquery(first_book.values("title")[:1])
).prefetch_related(Prefetch("titles", queryset=BookTitle.objects.all())).order_by(
    "first_book_name"
)
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I'd never have figured that out. I'd probably rename `first_book` to `first_book_title` to help with following what's going on.

Comment: Indeed, the naming could be optimized.